# install third party ssd in ibm xseries x3650 M4

Tags: hardware, ssd, ibm

i am in the process of purchasing a new network server, it's going to host SQL Server and Exchange so i would like to have the best possible IO, the ibm SSD i could afford it's the micron P400e, i would like to install something better for the OS, like the new Intel SSD DC S3700.

This SSD it's blazing fast and have capacitors to be a safe enterprise SSD.

Should i restrict myself to what IBM tries to sell me? i am happy with the mechanic counterparts and i am going to install some of this as well to have more free space but i would like to have the best SSD's i can too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with the m4, but I can confirm third party SSDs work fine with the regular (original) x3650.

If you have a support contract or a warranty, you should find out if your choice of hard drive affects it. That's the only reason I can think of to restrict yourself to what IBM sells you.

BTW: To remove the old drives from their sleds I needed a T10 torx screwdriver with a hollow point for compatibility with the weird tamper proof screws they use, which have a pin sticking up in the center preventing the use of a normal screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

yep it should work fine (as long as it matches the interface that you have setup on the server, sas, sata, etc), the raid controllers for that line are excellent as well, so you could possibly set up a few SSDs in an array that uses striping (raid 1,5,10, etc) for even better performance, although if you do decide to go that route, it would not hurt to upgrade from the ServeRAID M5110e (integrated raid controller) to the ServeRAID M5110 (has a battery backup which would allow you to safely enable writeback, few other performance upgrades)